# Sever Security: Blocking access to all* ports

Tags: centos, iptables, port

I've got a question - I currently have a VPS with OVH.

I have also searched but couldn't find anyone with a question exactly like mine!

Would it be practical to block all ports except 80 & 443? We use a remote MySQL server from which the VPS connects to, would this be affected?

I understand I'd need access to SSH, but honestly the way I see it - once the server is fully configured (as in, all web files in place, all server applications installed, etc.), I don't really need to touch it *that much*, and when I do there's KVM to manage the system or open the FTP ports.

I could look at maybe allowing access from my IP, but while it isn't dynamic in the sense it changes every other day, it does change from time to time.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

By default, MySQL uses port 3306. If this port is blocked, connections can't be made. However, your VPS *could* connect to a remote machine (whose port 3306 is open), if you have a firewall rule which allows traffic to and from a remote machine for the which your VPS initiated and established communications:

```
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

More info: [here](http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=iptables%20-A%20INPUT%20-m%20state%20--state%20ESTABLISHED%2CRELATED%20-j%20ACCEPT).

It's kind of impractical IMO to lock yourself out by closing the ssh port, but of course, that is a personal preference if you are able to access the machine via KVM.  If you are concerned, you can alway move the port the sshd daemon answers on from the standard 22 to anywhere you have a free port (say 32722). This way, if an attacker checks port 22, it will be closed and not offer ssh services. The attacker would have to do a port-by-port scan to detect that ssh services were offered on 32722, and most attackers are not willing to spend that kind of time when they have easier targets answering on 22.